# java - only reading and extracting one file to table

Tags: java

I have a program where I extract a text from PDF file and insert those text in a form of words into a table in MySQL.

I have two tables, a queue table and a word table.

The program retrieves a file from the queue table and build an index of words to the word table.

It works fine, but the problem is it only grabs one file but not the other files after that. Meaning, it only perform on the 1st file and then it closes. I am using a while loop and I disable autocommit so I have to commit it manually.

Did I make any mistake?

Code:

```
public void index1() throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        // Connection con1=con.connect();
        Connection con1 = con.connect();
        Statement statement = con1.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery( "select * from filequeue where Status='Active' LIMIT 5" );

        while ( rs.next() )
        {
            // get the filepath of the PDF document
            String path1 = rs.getString( 2 );
            int getNum = rs.getInt( 1 );
            // while running the process, update status : Processing
            //updateProcess_DB(getNum);
            Statement test = con1.createStatement();
            test.executeUpdate( "update filequeue SET STATUS ='Processing' where UniqueID=" + getNum );

            try
            {
                // call the index function

                    /*Indexing process = new Indexing();

                    process.index(path1);*/

                PDDocument document = PDDocument.load( new File( path1 ) );

                if ( !document.isEncrypted() )
                {
                    PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                    String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText( document );
                    String lines[] = pdfFileInText.split( "\\r?\\n" );
                    for ( String line : lines )
                    {
                        String[] words = line.split( " " );

                        String sql = "insert IGNORE into  test.indextable values (?,?);";

                        preparedStatement = con1.prepareStatement( sql );
                        int i = 0;
                        for ( String word : words )
                        {
                            // check if one or more special characters at end of string then remove OR
                            // check special characters in beginning of the string then remove
                            // insert every word directly to table db
                            word = word.replaceAll( "([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", "" );
                            preparedStatement.setString( 1, path1 );
                            preparedStatement.setString( 2, word );

                            preparedStatement.addBatch();

                            i++;
                            if ( i % 1000 == 0 )
                            {
                                preparedStatement.executeBatch();

                                System.out.print( "Add Thousand" );
                            }
                        }

                        if ( i > 0 )
                        {
                            preparedStatement.executeBatch();

                            System.out.print( "Add Remaining" );
                        }
                    }
                }
                // con1.commit();
                //  con1.close();
                preparedStatement.close();

                System.out.println( "Successfully commited changes to the database!" );

                // After completing the process, update status: Complete
                Statement pre = con1.createStatement();
                pre.executeUpdate( "update filequeue SET STATUS ='Complete' where UniqueID=" + getNum );

                con1.commit();

                preparedStatement.close();

                System.out.println( "Successfully commited changes to the database!" );

                con1.close();
                // updateComplete_DB(getNum);
            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                try
                {
                    System.err.println( e );

                    // updateError_DB(getNum);
                    // update status = Error in queue table if any error

                    Statement statement1 = con1.createStatement();
                    statement1.execute( "update filequeue SET STATUS ='Error' where UniqueID=" + getNum );

                    // add rollback function
                    rollbackEntries();
                }
                catch ( Exception e1 )
                {
                    System.out.println( "Could not rollback updates :" + e1.getMessage() );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: does ResultSet contain more than one file? did you debug your code? what's line break the program? are there any exceptions?

Comment: No exception but I figured it out. The culprit was con1.close(). It closes the connection somehow and unable to proceed with the second file,... etc